# Word spacing in Bootstrap button

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

Wnen I use buttons on my page the word spacing is too large by default.

```
.btn {
  word-spacing: 1px;
}
```

[image]

is it correct to use negative word spacing? It seems to do the trick.

```
.btn {
  word-spacing: -8px;
}
```

[image]

It's a little bit strange that it has this big spacing by default, but maybe it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Yes. According to the `word-spacing` documentation it's absolutely corrent. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#spacing-props

Answer (score 4):

Twitter Bootstrap (`bootstrap.css`||`bootstrap.min.css`) does **not** set `word-spacing` on `.btn` elements.

Inspect the element and see what stylesheet is adding that rule, because I can assure you it is not the default `bootstrap.css` (as of `v3.3.6`). You are either using a modified (non-standard) Twitter Bootstrap version or you are loading a different theme/framework on top of it.

And yes, as long as you load your own stylesheet last or you are using a stronger selector than the one that's currently setting the rule, you can override the `word-spacing` property on `.btn`s (whithout "breaking" anything else).

You are only changing the space between the letters of your buttons. As a sidenote, I recommend using `word-spacing: 0;`, which will render the font exactly as it has been designed, with proper kerning and ligatures.

Comment: It seems to break when I use glyph icons. If I remove the icon from the button it looks as I would expect it to do by default.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem with glyphicons inside bootstrap buttons. My problem was that I did forget to close the glyphicon span. Afterwards it displayed as normal.

Wrong example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">
  Text with spaces
</button>
```

Working example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
  Text with spaces
</button>
```